# WordPress Android app is not working

Tags: php, android, wordpress

I have a WordPress website that is working fine on web.

But the issue is that it is not working on android when we are using wordpress android app.

Error :

```
couldn't connect. enter full path to xmlrpc.php on your site and try again.
```

If any one has this issue before or any one have idea, Please help me.

I am stuck here.

link : [idealtile.biz](http://idealtile.biz)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've enabled remote blogging in your Wordpress settings:

Try the following:
1. Log in as a Wordpress admin on your site 
2. Navigate to the Wordpress Settings area
3. From Settings, navigate to the "Writing" area 
4. Make sure XML-RPC is checked

If this is done, you may have to specify the full path to your xmlrpc.php location. As in, http://idealtile.biz/xmlrpc.php (or whatever the actual path is).

Finally, make sure none of your URLs are directing to an alias when on Android. I don't know why this would be happening, but if it is, force in your Wordpress settings (Settings --> General) the actual URL of your site.

Comment: Hello,Thanks for your reply. All points are already set as you told. What you want to say in last para. please explain little.

Comment: If you're on Android devices while testing and the Android browser you're using is redirecting to some other URL that *points to* your URL, then that might be screwing this up and triggering the error. These threads may prove helpful; check them out and see if anything here helps: http://android.forums.wordpress.org/topic/unable-to-connet-using-wordpress-for-android-21 https://www.akeebabackup.com/support/desktop-utilities/3481-xml-rpc-layer-errorhelp.html